# What does mean impersonate account in hardhat?

Tags: ether, ethers.js, hardhat

I don't fully understand what it means to impersonate an account in a hardhat.

- Does it mean that I can access some wallet balance?
- Does it work only for forked chains?
- How does it work with contract address?